# How to display all of my running EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I switch to different regions frequently and sometimes I forget to turn off my running instance from a different region. I there a way (a website provided by Amazon?) to display all the running instances regardless of region?

Answer (score 3):

You can find all your running instances regardless of region and the cost they incur by going to [the Account Activity page](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary&) of your management console.

That dashboard is not real time and does not show one line per instance but it should help if you forget to turn off running instances.

Comment: The link now seems to redirect to the Billing Management Console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#